# How to focus and highlight the contents of an Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tabbing from one entry to another not only moves focus to the next entry but also highlights the value contained in the entry. Setting focus to an entry from the program only moves the focus but does NOT highlight the contents.

Is there a way to move the focus *and* highlight the contents of the Entry?

Comment: Of course. There are methods for selecting the text in a widget, so just call those methods when you change the focus.

Comment: Anyway, I would encourage you to write a simple _runnable_ example of code demonstrating your problem.